# Linq Group by Row into Column

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I have a csv imported into object

```
 obj_cellelist = (from line in File.ReadAllLines(pathCelle)
                             let columns = line.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None)
                             select new obj_celle()
                             {    
                                 Cgi = columns[0],
                                 zonaNis = columns[0].Length > 8 ? int.Parse(columns[0].Substring(5, 3)) : -1,
                                 codice_Sarf = columns[0].Length > 11 ? int.Parse(columns[0].Substring(8, 4)) : -1,
                                 IDCella = columns[1],
                                 Operatore = columns[2],
                                 Void = columns[3],
                                 Via = columns[4].Replace("''", "'"),
                                 Comune = columns[5].Replace("ï¿½", "A'"),
                                 Provincia = columns[6],
                                 Regione = provincie.Keys.Contains(columns[6]) ? provincie[columns[6]] : "",
                                 Nazione = columns[7],
                                 Latitudine = decimal.Parse(columns[8].Replace('.', ',')) ,
                                 Longitudine = decimal.Parse(columns[9].Replace('.', ',')) ,
                                 Void1 = columns[10], 
                                 Azimuth = columns[11].Length > 0 ? int.Parse(columns[11]) : -1 }).ToList();
```

I need to group by Longitudine and Latitudine  and get all different Azimuth  in row. There are max three different Azimuth for each Latitudine,Longitudine.
Other value are the same except cgi, i don't need.
New object should contain
zonaNis,codice_Sarf,IDCella,Operatore,Void,Via,Comune,Provincia,Regione,Nazione,Latitudine,Longitudine,Void1,Azimuth1,Azimuth2,Azimuth3

Example :

861###3OF034AA###VODAFONE######STRADA TEST###NOLA###AR###ITALY###43.74619685###11.71866206######110

862###3OF034AA###VODAFONE######STRADA TEST###NOLA###AR###ITALY###43.74619685###11.71866206######240

864###3OF034AA###VODAFONE######STRADA TEST###NOLA###AR###ITALY###43.74619685###11.71866206######110

865###3OF034AA###VODAFONE######STRADA TEST###NOLA###AR###ITALY###43.74619685###11.71866206######240

867###3OF034AA###VODAFONE######STRADA TEST###NOLA###AR###ITALY###43.74619685###11.71866206######110

868###3OF034AA###VODAFONE######STRADA TEST###NOLA###AR###ITALY###43.74619685###11.71866206######240

Output in object Should be

3OF034AA###VODAFONE######STRADA TEST###NOLA###AR###ITALY###43.74619685###11.71866206######110###240

Comment: Please [mcve]. Make a little exemple with name, lat, long, what ever and show use the expected result. And they way you calculate it.

Comment: Because for now it's unclear. because azimuth is between point.

Comment: Are you trying to Convert one Csv to an other Csv format?

Answer (score 0):

```
obj_cellelist
   .GroupBy(p => new { Lat = p.Latitudine, Long = p.Longitudine })
   .Select(g => new { place = g.Key, azimuths = g.Select(a => a.Azimuth).Disctinct() })
   .ToList();
```

This will yield you a list of objects with two properties. First property is of type obj_celle and the other property is List of distinct azimuths.

Comment: Not working. I need new zonaNis,codice_Sarf,IDCella,Operatore,Void,Via,Comune,Provincia,Regione,Nazione,Latitudine,Longitudine,Void1,Azimuth1,Azimuth2,Azimuth3

Comment: You have all of those values in property place and azimuths are in property azimuths as a List<int>. How many azimuths can there be and is it crucial that all of them are displayed as a separate column rather than a single property of List<int>?